# Use EXISTS in SQL for multiple select

Tags: sql, exists

I have a table STATUSES which contain columns NAME and ACTIVE_FLAG.The column value of NAME may have new, pending, cancel. I want to generate a new output for the count of each NAME with ACTIVE_FLAG=Y

By thinking to use `EXISTS` to select records for single NAME,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS PENDING
FROM STATUSES
WHERE EXISTS (select NAME from STATUSES where NAME='Pending' and ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y')
```

Anyway if I can join other statuses count in a single SQL?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data nand desired results.

Comment: Why exactly are you using exists? Why not using the where filter directly?

Comment: ^^ @Scarnet Looking at that is like going to the store -- To go to the store ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this as i don't see any need to use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT sum(case when name='Pending' then 1 else 0 end) AS PENDING,
sum(case when name='new' then 1 else 0 end) AS NEW,
sum(case when name='cancel' then 1 else 0 end) AS CANCEL
FROM STATUSES
WHERE ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
```

[SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/42b9d/2)

Comment: It's great that your problem is sorted out. Don't forget to follow [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I want to join with several tables in CASE condition. I have 2 extra tables: 
ALERT_CASE_HEADER
-alert_key
ALERT_ITEM
-entity_key
-entity_name='Active Alert'
Both tables use alert_key and entity_key to link. The summation of case only take place if both keys are same value and entity_name='Active Alert'.In this case ACTIVE_FLAG is no longer needed

Comment: Can I do something like this? I tested the script but seem so slow

SELECT sum(case when s.name='Pending' and ach.alert_key = ai.entity_key and ai.entity_name='Active Alert' then 1 else 0 end) AS PENDING,
sum(case when s.name='new' and ach.alert_key = ai.entity_key and ai.entity_name='Active Alert' then 1 else 0 end) AS NEW,
sum(case when s.name='cancel' and ach.alert_key = ai.entity_key and ai.entity_name='Active Alert' then 1 else 0 end) AS CANCEL
FROM STATUSES s,ALERT_CASE_HEADER ach,ALERT_ITEM ai;

Comment: Please post a new question instead and provide this query with formatting. Very tough to understand the query in comment section.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `count` and `group by`

```
SELECT 
    name
  , count(*)
FROM statuses
WHERE active_flag = 'Y'
GROUP BY name
```